# How to calculate date from no. of months span in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I have 1 date column `date=2017-01-01` and I have `no_of_months` column having values like `20,30,50` etc.

Now, our date is 1 Jan 17, after adding 20 months I will have `outputDate`=1 Oct 2018

How to get `outputDate` as result?

Comment: If the syntax worked you should mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function `DATE_ADD`

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(dateColumn, INTERVAL no_of_months MONTH) outputDate
```

in plain text as syntax

```
 SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE('2017-01-01'), INTERVAL 20 MONTH) outputDate
```